# I want to make a button (HTML button) , that never change it's Postion,

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to make a button (HTML button) , that never change it's Postion, while i resize or Restore the browser the Button will remain in same Postion ... How can i create ?

Comment: use style="position:fixed;"

Comment: You can use the css property `position:fixed`

Comment: Never changes its position relative to what? The browser window? Its container?

Comment: no need for javascript for this...

Answer (score 2):

Use the position CSS tag -

```
 .buttonClass{
     position:fixed;
     left:100px;
     top:150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
     position:fixed;
     left:200px;
     top:200px;
 }
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qqM6/)